# Converting uppercase html tags to lowercase

Tags: php, regex

I have the following to replace uppercase HTML tags with lowercase ones.

```
$output = preg_replace("%<(/?[A-Z].*?)>%s",strtolower('$1'),$output);
```

The matching seems to be working well (in my RegEx testing site), but the replacement isn't.

```
<EM>TEST</EM> becomes EMTEST/EM
```

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction on this.

Comment: The right direction would be to not write your HTML tags in uppercase :)

Comment: Yes, trying to avoid this entirely -- but there are still some areas of our application where it's problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `strtolower` on `"$1"` and then using the result (which is just `$1` again) to replace to.

Instead, use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback) and have the callback be: `function($m) {return strtolower($m[0]);}`

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = preg_replace("%<(/?[A-Z].*?)>%se", "'<' . strtolower('\\1') . '>'",$output);
```

**Edit**: forgot to mention that you should *NOT* use `preg` for HTML stuff :) DOMDocument is a far better choice.

Comment: Thx. Starting to look into DomDocument and I see what you mean.

Comment: By the way, the `e` modifier is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.